# PHP: How to keep NULL when imploding array

Tags: php, arrays

In my insert method of my database class I pass the parameters as an array:

```
$sql='INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` (`'.implode('`, `',array_keys($params)).'`) VALUES ("' . implode('", "', $params) . '")';
```

As you can see, the array gets imploded.

My `$params` for example looks like this:

```
$params = [
  'field1' => 'sometext1',
  'field2' => 'sometext2',
  'stamp_created' => NULL
]
```

My field `'stamp_created'` must be set NULL, so that the date of creation gets displayed in the data row in the database. However, imploding the array turns `NULL` to an empty string `""`:

```
VALUES ('sometext1', 'sometext2', '')
```

How do I achieve that `NULL` does not get ignored in my implode operation? My desired result is:

```
VALUES ('sometext1', 'sometext2', NULL)
```

Comment: Sorry I downvoted your question but your approach is terribly insecure and allow SQL injections. You shouldn't built your query like that. You should use prepared statements, it's lot safer

Answer (score 3):

PHP's `null`, when cast to a string, results in an empty string. What you want instead is the string `'NULL'`, so you'll have to do a little more manual work to achieve that:

```
$values = join(', ', array_map(function ($value) {
    return $value === null ? 'NULL' : "'$value'";
}, $params));
```

Note that this code is terribly prone to SQL injection and you should shift your entire approach to prepared statements; just saying...